# UserControl default value for dependency property of type DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, user-controls, dependency-properties, default-value

I have a simple EntriesViewModel that stores a list of items as well as supporting Add/Remove commands. (Add/Remove commanding left out)

```
public class EntriesViewModel
{
    public ObservableCollection<string> Entries { get; private set; }

    public EntriesViewModel()
    {
        Entries = new ObservableCollection<string>() { "One", "Two", "Three" };
    }
}
```

To view this I have created a simple EntriesEditor usercontrol that uses a listbox to display the entries and buttons to Add/Remove (Add/Remove commanding left out)

```
 public partial class EntriesEditor : UserControl
{
    public EntriesEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDefaults.EntriesEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:UserControlDefaults"
         VerticalAlignment="Top">
<DockPanel Height="200">
    <UniformGrid Columns="2"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Add" />
        <Button Content="Remove" />
    </UniformGrid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
             ItemTemplate="{Binding EntryTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type l:EntriesEditor}}}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

And is used as so :

```
<l:EntriesEditor DataContext="{Binding EntriesViewModel}"/>
```

I now want the EntriesEditor to support the ability to define a custom ItemTemplate. So I add an EntryTemplate property.

```
public partial class EntriesEditor : UserControl
{
    public DataTemplate EntryTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(EntryTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(EntryTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty EntryTemplateProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EntryTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(EntriesEditor), new PropertyMetadata(null));

    public EntriesEditor()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}

<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDefaults.EntriesEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:UserControlDefaults"
         VerticalAlignment="Top">
<DockPanel Height="200">
    <UniformGrid Columns="2"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Add" />
        <Button Content="Remove" />
    </UniformGrid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
             ItemTemplate="{Binding EntryTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type l:EntriesEditor}}}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

Which is used as so:

```
<l:EntriesEditor DataContext="{Binding EntriesViewModel}">
    <l:EntriesEditor.EntryTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Green"
                    Padding="5">
                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </l:EntriesEditor.EntryTemplate>
</l:EntriesEditor>
```

But now I want to define a default EntryTemplate within the EntriesEditor control, how would I do this?

The only way I can think of, is like this :

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlDefaults.EntriesEditor"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:l="clr-namespace:UserControlDefaults"
         VerticalAlignment="Top">

<UserControl.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type l:EntriesEditor}">
        <Setter Property="EntryTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderThickness="2"
                            BorderBrush="Red">
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" />
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</UserControl.Style>

<DockPanel Height="200">
    <UniformGrid Columns="2"
                 DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
        <Button Content="Add" />
        <Button Content="Remove" />
    </UniformGrid>
    <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Entries}"
             ItemTemplate="{Binding EntryTemplate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type l:EntriesEditor}}}"/>
</DockPanel>
```

But that doesn't seem right.

Comment: @pastillman - Why it doesn't seems right?

Comment: It felt like a bit of a workaround, but if this is the correct way ... ok then! :)

Comment: The DataTemplateSelector was designed just for that purpose.